# Why a notation node is extracted when parsing xml?

Tags: python, xml

While trying to parse xml file, I faced a problem that I don't understand.
In the xml file, there is one "report" node. However, when parsing, the top node has two "report" nodes. One has type number 10, which is notation node, and the other has type number 1, element node. I don't understand why the top document node has two "report" nodes even though there is one "report" node in the xml...

Here is the case.

In xml,

```
<report name="JaCoCo Ant Example">
<sessioninfo id="..." start="..." dump="..."/>
<package name="org/apache/jmeter/util">
<class name="org/apache/jmeter/util/ClassFinder$Test">...</class>
...
</package>
</report>
```

In python,

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parse
>>> dom=parse('xml file path')
>>> dom.nodeName
'#document'
>>> reportNode=dom.childNodes
>>> len(reportNode)
2 <- "I don't know why this is 2, not 1?"
>>> reportNode[0].nodeName
u'report'
>>> reportNode[1].nodeName
u'report'
>>> reportNode[0].nodeType
10
>>> reportNode[1].nodeType
1
```

**Update:**
There are nodes that do not appear when I opened the xml file with chrome browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE report PUBLIC "-//JACOCO//DTD Report 1.0//EN" "report.dtd">
<report name="JaCoCo Ant Example">...</report>
```

When I remove "!DOCTYPE report..." node, the node length is one. Thus, that node is extracted when the xml file is parsed. But I'm still wondering that its nodeName is u'report'...

Comment: I ran your example and `len(reportNode)` ==> 1. That tells me the XML in the example is not the same XML you saw earlier.

Comment: @HaiVu I found the reason. The XML file also has this node: <!DOCTYPE report PUBLIC "-//JACOCO//DTD Report 1.0//EN" "report.dtd">. But Chrome browser doesn't show the node. Thank you for pointing it out.